# Does my BMW e36 320i 1992 have a Gearbox cooler

Tags: bmw, cooling-system, gears

Does the BMW e36 come equipped with gearbox coolers, if not, can I install one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BMW do have trans coolers for their vehicles with auto transmissions. They are embedded in the cooling system radiator.